# Could elementary particles have started as black holes?

Tags: black-holes, elementary-particles

If you calculate the Schwarzschild radius of an electron you get a value around $10^{-50}$, give or take a few orders of magnitude.

Now, the electric field of a charged black hole can be felt outside the hole. That is if the hole came into being by the collapse of mass. Elementary particles obviously didn't originate from a collapse of mass. If a black hole is not the effect of collapsing mass (the eternal black hole), then the existence of the electric field outside the hole is accounted for by white holes (see [here](https://facultystaff.richmond.edu/%7Eebunn/ajpans/ajpans.html)). But elementary particles aren't eternal either. They have their origin a long time ago, near the beginning of the universe. So you would expect the electric field (or any field) not to be present away from the particles.

Does this prove that elementary particles are not black holes? If they *were*, photon fields or other fields would not be able to react with elementary particles. They could enter the particles but not emerge from them. The fields could not be excited through all of the space outside the event horizon.

I know that spacetime should be considered quantized, but a full theory of quantized spacetime is not there (though Loop Quantum Gravity comes close). Is the mere fact that (force)fields *are* present proof that particles are not point-like or that spacetime has to be quantized? Are point particles to be replaced by extended structures which don't have an associated event horizon (like strings, though not necessarily)? Merely stating that distances below the Planck length have no meaning is admitting ignorance, I think.

Comment: @Brick No. That question asks if black holes end up as elementary particles. I ask if they could have started as them. I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: *If you calculate the Schwarzschild radius of an electron you get a value around $10^{−50}$.* $10^{-50}$ is not a length.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few things to consider:

1. The electron has a specific charge that corresponds to a so-called over-extremal [Reissner Nordström black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric). In other words, if you take a macroscopic black hole and make its charge to mass ratio the same as an electron, it will become a naked singularity. Such singularities are assumed to be unstable to quantum effects, so semi-classical theory gives us a big shrug on what should a space-time singularity with the mass and charge of an electron look like.
2. If any elementary particle was a black hole, or at least some sort of space-time singularity it would not matter for our theory and experiment too much. The thing is that the singular behaviour would happen on such short scales that we can ignore it and replace whatever is happening on the shortest scale by an effective "point particle". In theoretical-physics jargon this is known as an effective field theory. Current theories are considered as "fundamental" if they do not *need* new stuff to happen on the shortest scale for the theory to work everywhere (this is known as [renormalizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization#Renormalizability)). So if we say a particle is a "fundamental particle", we are saying we do not *need* it to be anything else than just a particle.
3. The elementary particles we know right here and right can be much younger than the Early universe. Particles decay and transform all the time (even absolutely fundamental ones). In particular, they transfer charge (and other quantum numbers) between one another, and neutral fundamental particles can decay into two particles of opposite charges. There is no classical picture for this happening in some sort of "tiny black hole" scenario. This has to be an entirely and completely *quantum* process. However, since no consistent quantum gravity exists (at least one in our universe agreeing with our current observations), there is no answer to what should be happening there.

In short, we do not know!

Comment: Why would an electron be a naked singularity? And what about the other particles, like the muon and the tau? They have a bigger mass, so the ratio mass/charge is different. In favor of mass.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder For an extremal black hole with charge of the electron you'd need a particle with mass about 2 micrograms, just an order of magnitide below the Planck mass.

Comment: @OON so the electron can't be a naked singularity?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder How do you reach that conclusion from what is written? The electron and any known (and any hypothetical particle with almost Planckian mass) would be a naked singularity if we would treat it as a classical black hole. However the naked singularity means theory becoming useless. General relativity doesn't tell you what will happen with the stuff falling on the naked singularity or what originates from it or how to resolve various infinite observables. It's just a sign that your notions doesn't work there. So "electron is a naked singularity" is a meaningless statement

Comment: @OON Well, it is written in the answer: "In other words, if you take a macroscopic black hole and make its charge to mass ratio the same as an electron, it will become a naked singularity" But how can this be if that ratio is much bigger (as you write)?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Ok, you can say that it can't be a naked singularity in the sense that the inverse statement makes no sense)

Comment: @OON That's exactly my question. It can't be a naked singularity. So, is it a black hole with an event horizon (about $10^{-50}(m)$, so quite small)? It can't be an eternal black hole and it can't be a hole caused by collapse. So how can a photon field make contact with particle fields outside the electron?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder You're missing the whole point. You can't treat the electron as a classical black hole because GR breaks down. GR tells you it should be a naked singularity. But the naked singularity makes theory useless. And we know that by that point it should actually stop working.

Comment: @OON That is the reaction I already expected. As I stated in the end of my question...GR tells you it can't be a naked singularity. The mass is too small for that, as you stated yourself in the first comment.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder GR tells you that you get the naked singularity if the charge is above the critical value so that $k_e\frac{Q^2 G}{c^4}>\frac{r_s^2}{4}$ where $r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$. So that the electron is so light means that the classical solution has the naked singularity and this tells you that your treatment is wrong. The same is true for any known particle because their mass is too small. If the mass was large, more than 2 micrograms than it would be a black hole. Not the other way around!

Comment: @OON Yes indeed. I realized it. But what about the electrically neutral particles? They have another charge but nevertheless.

Comment: @OON isn't the classical solution based on a collection of charged particles? That is, will the solution still apply for a single charge (which has no constituting charges making the self-energy high)? Why should a small self energy contribute to the geometry of a black hole?